# Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Online Server Changes (Wave Update) Breaking Portals

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

We have some major issues on several SharePoint 2013 Online Portals (5000+ users!) with custom branding.

Apparently the HTML structure is changed?

What kind of (Wave) change is this?

This cannot be right.

Customers are getting frustrated.

Is there anyone else experiencing these weird changes?

I cannot add images so please go to this MSDN article for the images:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7e0bc19c-97e7-415b-afcc-1df4ad60a9fe/microsoft-server-changes-wave-update-breaks-large-portals